# How to match values from one column to second column with multiple values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
Name  Dept
abc   Genteic|Biology|Chemical Engineering
def   Physics|Chemical Engineering|Astrophysics
xyz   Chemical Engineering|Astrophysics
klm   Biology|Astrophysics
nop   Chemical Engineering|Astrophysics
```

The first column contains name and second column shows the various departments they are associated with. I want to know number of people working in each department.
For ex: In biology dept how many people are associated with.
The code i have so for is :

```
import  pandas as pd
import json
import requests
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError
from requests.exceptions import ReadTimeout
import csv

def author_name(dataframe):
      response = get_url(term)
      return response

def get_url(term):
print(term)
response = resp.content
data = json.loads(response)
print(data) 

try:
    if data['author-retrieval-response']['subject-areas']['subject-area'] != 'null':
        myvar = data['author-retrieval-response']['subject-areas']['subject-area']['@abbrev']
        myvar = myvar.split('|')

    else:
        data['author-retrieval-response']['subject-areas']['subject-area'] = 'null'
        auth_empty =  data['author-retrieval-response']['subject-areas']['subject-area']['@abbrev']
        print(auth_empty)
except:
    pass

if __name__ =='__main__': 

out = open('out.csv', 'w',encoding='utf-8', newline="\n")
csvwriter = csv.writer(out)
header = ['Scopus ID', 'Title', 'Abstract', 'Affilaition', 'Authors', 
'Citation', 'Pub_Date']       

dataframe = pd.read_csv('author.csv', usecols='auth_name')
for i, row in dataframe.iterrows():
      term = (str(row[0]))
      response = author_name(dataframe)
      csvwriter.writerow(response)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks !!

Comment: I dont see where this is a regex-question. Just iterate over your list, and increment the corresponding counter, if the person works in Dept. XY. What do you need regex for?!

Comment: @TomMekken    I tagged regex it there could be any help in string matching.

Comment: you want to use python? Then just use: strings `split()` method.
The best would be, if you'd show us your code, of what you have tried so far to achieve your goal

Comment: @TomMekken I have added the code, I am using `split()`. But Im stuck on how to get the number of authors  working in each department.

Comment: for the next time that you post code, I would recommend just to paste the code, that you have a question about. You didn't need to post your API-Keys here ;)
That does not help nobody and is only confusing while figuring out, where the problem is in your code. For your next question, please read here: [how to provide mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote you a very simple pythonscript that does, what I think you want it to do. 
I ignored that fact that the inputfile is a csv-file, and that there do exist libraries for parsing it. The following is just a quick and dirty solution, to hint you into the right direction. I would recommend you to improve this snippet:

- use a csv-library to process the file
- <s>use a kind of dictionary for your variables</s> ***edit:*** already done
- <s>try to get rid of the string-comparison (p.e. use the subject as a key for your dictionary)</s> ***edit:*** already done

**input.csv**

```
abc   Genteic|Biology|Chemical Engineering
def   Physics|Chemical Engineering|Astrophysics
xyz   Chemical Engineering|Astrophysics
klm   Biology|Astrophysics
nop   Chemical Engineering|Astrophysics
```

**main.py**

```
counters = {"Biology":0, "Genteic":0, "Chemical Engineering":0, "Physics":0, "Astrophysics":0}

csv_file = open("input.csv", "r")

for line in csv_file.read().splitlines():
    arr=line.split("   ")
    name=arr[0]
    professions=arr[1]
    for subj in professions.split("|"):
        counters[subj] += 1

csv_file.close()
print("There are %s teachers working in Biology" % counters["Biology"])
print("There are %s teachers working in Genteic" % counters["Genteic"])
print("There are %s teachers working in Chemical Engineering" % counters["Chemical Engineering"])
print("There are %s teachers working in Physics" % counters["Physics"])
print("There are %s teachers working in Astrophysics" % counters["Astrophysics"])
```

call of `python3 main.py` results in:

```
There are 2 teachers working in Biology
There are 1 teachers working in Genteic
There are 4 teachers working in Chemical Engineering
There are 1 teachers working in Physics
There are 4 teachers working in Astrophysics
```

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, please click the gray "check"-arrow on the question, to mark this question as "solved" :)

Comment: In the statement `if(subj == "Biology"):                                                                        
            num_of_bio_teachers+=1 ` I have multiple values.

Comment: thats what I meant with the second point in my "you should improve the following"-list: use a kind of dictionary, where you map the subject to its corresponding count-variable ... then you could increase the mapped value instead. I will edit my answer accordingly ...

Comment: Im getting an error in line `professions=arr[1] ` Indexerror : List index out of range`

Comment: okay mate, I now wrote a script that you can copy and execute. I even provided you the input-file. everything works (i tested it). I hope that from here on, you'd be able to implement everything you need in your own program. If not, throw a look an a good python-debugger. That should help you to investigate your bugs.
Good Luck :)